# crystal report - the main and sub report not linked all records duplicate

Tags: sql, database, crystal-reports

I run a crystal report in case:

- the main report has 2 duplicate  records

- the sub report has 5 record (the same Pol_ID, the other fields are different)

The main linked to the sub by Pol_ID

After running the report, I have 2 page with:

-page 1 has not linked to sub-report

-pafe 2 has enough information (it has main and sub)

-data in main-report in page 1 & 2 is same

So why page 1 has not linked to sub?

Comment: didn't get your problem...

Comment: do you have groups on your report?

Comment: yes, the report has group in the main-report either the sub-report.